# Phonegap 1.0 Android capture video

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video-capture

I am trying to capture an image and failed!

I use phonegap 1.0 and jquery mobile 1.0b2.

The following line starts the device's internal videorecorder!

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
```

And here are the callbacks:

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    console.log("capturing video sucessfully finished");      
}

function captureError(error) {
    console.log("video capture error + " + error.code);
}
```

if i quit recording i get back to my app and i get the console log of captureError but with the error.code as "undefined".

if i try to store the video the captureSuccess won't be called and my application restarts!

Does somebody has an solution to this issue!?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if somebody is interested, i got the answer to this problem from the phone gap github issue list, where i also posted this question!

it worked after i put the following option to my activity in the android manifest.xml file.

**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"**

cu